# How to nest a RadioGroup with dynamic lists of RadioButton inside each row/item of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-radiogroup

I need a layout like this:

[image]

The Red titles are the first level array from `dish_options` and the `RadioButtons` are a populated from an array `items`inside `dish_options` of the json:

[image]

As you may notice the `dish_options` is an array, which might have many more object inside one of the keys of this `dish_options` might store an `items` arrays.

I tried using `getItemViewType()` and set different layouts for first level `dish_options` (red title) and implemented a different layout for the `RadioButton` in each row of `items`the problem is that I have to use RadioGroup to make `RadioButton` unique (only 1 click per radiogroup). So I'm stucked with this and no idea how to proceed.

Should I nest a RecyclerView inside each row of the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try to this code  https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

This is a single adapter having groupSection or GroupItem maintained with one recyclerView 
because your design is not too much complex thismight be helpful

first run "`draggable with section`" as it is ... and then change the layout as per your need

you may need to remove the draggable interface with its methods as I guess you don't need them

`implements DraggableItemAdapter<DraggableWithSectionExampleAdapter.MyViewHolder>`

Carefully  have a look at this class and you might need to integrate your JSON data some how in this way, or inside this classes(I suggest if your not an expert) comment line no 37 - 53 and atry to replicate with your data

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/h6ah4i/android/example/advrecyclerview/common/data/ExampleSectionDataProvider.java

As you required to select some or None Items from the group, ... you can implement a check-box  or switch the images and set the 0 for unchecked or 1 for checked to your data class (I'm mean your POJO class you generated from JSON or you can even maintain a key in json )